# Digitally Signing scripts in [VSCODE]

Tags: powershell, vbscript, visual-studio-code, sign, wsh

In our environment the two main scripting languages that we use are VBScript/WScript and PowerShell.  Our PowerShell is set up so that all scripts have to be digitally signed.  Inside the PowerShell ISE we added a menu item that saves the current working script and digitally signs it.  We currently use a different editor for VBS/Wscript.  Is there a way in VSCode to allow us to run a function within the environment to digitally sign the current PowerShell scripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found my answer:

```
Register-EditorCommand -Name SignCurrentScript -DisplayName 'Sign Current Script' -ScriptBlock {
    $cert = (Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My -CodeSigningCert)[0]
    $currentFile = $psEditor.GetEditorContext().CurrentFile.Path
    Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $cert -FilePath $currentFile
}
```

Comment: What do I do with this? Run it (how?), or add it to a config file?

Comment: Add it to your 
 C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1
 
hit Shift-Alt-S it should be listed there.